# 2010 Toyota RAV4 air conditioning blows warm instead of cold

Tags: toyota, ac, rav4, refrigerant

Since it's a second vehicle and I don't use it much, I don't really want to spend money on a diagnosis and have been trying to research how I could diagnose (and maybe fix) the problem myself.

https://www.toyotaofeasley.com/air-conditioning-isnt-cold/ says:

**1. A refrigerant leak**

**If the air still isn't cold** after adding more Freon then there is probably another leak in the system.

2. A bad compressor

There will usually be a loud noise when you attempt to turn on your air conditioner if the compressor is broken.

**3. A clogged orifice tube**

The orifice tube is located between the condenser in the front of the radiator and the evaporator in the passenger compartment. If there is an obstruction in the tube, it will stop the refrigerant from reaching the evaporator, **causing your system to blow warm air.**

**4. It loses its charge**

A very common cause of an air conditioner **not being cold is that the refrigerant needs to be recharged**. You can charge it yourself with a charger kit, but you may be more comfortable bringing it to the shop for an easy fix.

5. The fan is damaged

You can recognize this symptom if you can feel cold air but it is not actually blowing.

6. Blend Air Door is jammed
7. Dirt inside the system
8. Moisture in the air conditioning system

I would guess my problem is #1, 3, or 4.

Do you have any more detailed tips about how I could narrow it down? What should I inspect?

Comment: Which ones have you done so far? The items you suggest are relevant, so hopefully you have some progress to report.

Comment: Do you know if you have any gas in the system?

Comment: #1 and #4 actually sound the same to me, and I'm not sure how to check the Freon level myself. For #3, I haven't found any manual/diagrams that show where I should be looking for an "orifice tube" and how I would inspect and unclog it.

Comment: @HandyHowie The fuel tank has gasoline of course, and if you are asking about gas as opposed to liquid or solid, I'm not sure what you mean by "system" and how I can check. I'd love any tips! Thanks :-)

Comment: I meant refrigerant gas in the air conditioning system.

Comment: To check if you have any refrigerant in the system, you could very briefly press the nipple on the low pressure service valve.  If you don’t get a sound like you would when letting air out of a car tyre, then you have no refrigerant.  Only do this when the engine hasn’t been running for a while.